# How to loop through a dictionary defined in different method

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is defined in SetStoreInfoDetail:

```
public void SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID)
        {

            _mgr = new CRCManager();

            StoreInfo StoreInfoFields = new StoreInfo();

            List<StoreInfo> StoreList = _mgr.GetStoreList(issueID);


            var StoreInfoMapping = StoreList.ToDictionary(keySelector: row => row.store_info_id);
}
```

I want to loop through StoreInfoMapping:

Current Code:

```
foreach (StoreInfo store_info_id in StoreInfoMapping)
{
Do Something
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggetions are appreciated.

Comment: The dictionary needs to be in scope. You could return the dictionary from the method.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, depending on how your code is structured.  How does the logic flow get from the first code snippet to the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have instantiated a Dictionary (`StoreInfoMapping`) as the last thing in your method, it is then unused and disposed of.

One way to solve this is to have a `Dictionary<key,value>` as the method's return type

```
public Dictionary<int,StoreInfo> SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID)
```

and then where you create the variable you can return it

```
return StoreList.ToDictionary(keySelector: row => row.store_info_id);
```

Finally, in the code where you want to reference it you can do this

```
//your id = id in this example and the dictionary is assumed to be an <int, StoreInfo>
StoreInfoMapping = SetStoreInfoDetail(id)

foreach (StoreInfo store_info_id in StoreInfoMapping)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

After reading your comment, I would suggest instead that you can use ref or out variables

```
public void SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID, ref Dictionary<int, StoreInfo> theDict)
```

This would then be called like so

```
StoreInfoMapping = new Dictionary<int, StoreInfo>();
SetStoreInfoDetail(id, ref StoreInfoMapping);
```

In the method itself, instead of instantiating the dictionary, you can use the one passed in, any changes made will be reflected outside of the method.

Comment: I cannot change the method type to public Dictionary<int,StoreInfo> SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID) because it will conflict with my other logic used somewhere else.

Comment: @Programmermid How about now?

Answer (score 0):

Try Looping the dictionary using:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,StoreInfo> info in StorInfoMapping) 
{
    //Key is the store_info_id
    //Value is the StoreInfo object        
}
```

If you want the dictionary to be accessed by other methods.

```
class StoreInfoClass //Your class
{
   //Define dictionary here so it can be accessed by all function within the class
   private Dictionary<int,StoreInfo> StoreInfoMapping;

   //Your Functions
   public void SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID)
   {

        _mgr = new CRCManager();

        StoreInfo StoreInfoFields = new StoreInfo();

        List<StoreInfo> StoreList = _mgr.GetStoreList(issueID);


        StoreInfoMapping = StoreList.ToDictionary(keySelector: row => row.store_info_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but my dictionary is defined in another method. So I am looking for a way to call dictionary from another method.

Comment: You can either create a variable (dictionary) within the class that can be accessed by both functions or make this current function SetStoreInfoDetail(int issueID) return a dictionary.